# How to iterate over Object properties of an input parameter

Tags: azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I have an Azure Automation Powershell Workflow:

```
workflow wf
{
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [object] $p
  )
  inlinescript
  {
    # ...
  }
}
```

I am testing it using the Test pane and passing the value as `{"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"}`. I have also tried `{"FirstName"="John";"LastName"="Smith"}` and adding the `@` in front of both cases.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-input-parameters)

> If your runbook has an object type input parameter, then use a PowerShell hashtable with (name,value) pairs to pass in a value. For example, if you have the following parameter in a runbook: `[Parameter (Mandatory = $true)][object] $FullName` then you pass the following value to the parameter: `@{"FirstName"="Joe";"MiddleName"="Bob";"LastName"="Smith"}`

But in all of my tests `$p` is null.

How do I define an actual object, pass it in, and then iterate over the property names and values?

Comment: Does the value actually get passed as an object or is it passed as a (JSON) string?

Comment: excuse my ignorance in PowerShell, but how do I know?

Comment: Try without an explicit type (`[parameter(Mandatory=$True)]$p`) and check the type (`Write-Host $p.GetType().FullName`).

Comment: Interesting, after doing `Write-Output "Type: " $p.GetType().FullName` I get the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." Both with explicit and no type

Comment: Then nothing is getting passed to the parameter, obviously. I have too little experience with Azure and workflows to be able to assist further, though.

Comment: I found the problem, I had forgotten to specify that this is running as an inline-script activity of the Workflow and therefore I had to use `$Using:p` to access the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the input parameters within an activity of the PowerShell Workflow, you have to do via the `$Using` keyword. Once I figure that one out I was able to see the type was being passed in as a string. So I had to convert from a json string to an object by using `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet. I was then able to iterate through the properties by getting the `Properties` property of the `PSObject`:

```
$pObj = $Using:p | ConvertFrom-Json
ForEach ($pr in $pObj.PSObject.Properties)
{
   #$pr.Name
   #$pr.Value
}
```